# PyDub: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid. While recognize_google transcribe text. FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, speech-recognition, pydub, transcription

I am trying to transcribe the audio to text using the pydub and speech recognition library. My code is successfully converting the '.mp3' file to '.wav' but while conversion/transcribing using recognize_google library I am getting this error

"ERROR: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid. "

The twist is when i am running this script directly its running fine but when my API created in Flask calls this script its failing.

My Flask application is HOSTED on IIS Server.

```
with recaptcha_audio as source:
recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
audio = recognizer.record(source)
sleep(2)
try:            
    transcribed = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="en-US")
except Exception as e:
    log.error(f"-----------------------ERROR: {str(e)}")
    return f"-----------------------ERROR: {str(e)}"
```

I tried changing the audio files and also manipulating the AudioSegment.py subprocess implementation with "stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL".

No success yet.
Please suggest a way out for my Flask Application with IIS, to implement this script.

Answer (score 0):

After spending several days investigating, I've identified a solution for `recognizer.recognize_google` or Speech-to-Text (STT) issues when working with virtual environments and IIS deployment.

The key to resolving the issue is ensuring that you create and use the `virtual environment` instead use Python from `c:/python`.

**Here's a concise guide:**

1. **Create Virtual Environment:**

   Use the following command to create a virtual environment named 'env':

   `python -m venv env`
2. **Activate Virtual Environment:**

   `.\env\Scripts\activate`
3. **Dependency Installation**

   While the virtual environment is active, install the required pip libraries for your project